# Android GPS position

Tags: android, mobile, gps, location

The GPS in phones is known to be not so accurate. But what I want to do is this.
When the user reaches a particular spot he saves it.When he comes again near that spot(5 metres range) the application should do something. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to write an application? Are you looking for an existing application? It's not clear what kind of solution you are looking for.

Comment: So something like Apple's Reminders?

Comment: This question is very unclear, please try to make it more understandable.

Comment: If you're not so strict about the 5m then YES, there is a way to achieve this. And it is so simple that a little bit of googling should provide you with an answer.

Comment: See the answer titled Using Proximity Alerts with Google Maps activity

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by David Schwartz what you ask is a little bit vague, however, assuming that you want to do something yourself, you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105269/finding-a-coordinate-in-a-circle) SO question useful. In this question, they provide various methods to see if a point is within a circle.

I recommend however, that you increase the radius you would like to use. GPS varies between 5m to 50m, and that is usually in optimal conditions. If you throw in some buildings and other structures that can quite easily increase this margin of error.